# How to Build a Spray Project Created from Official Template

Tags: scala, sbt, spray

I've created a new Spray project starting from official template:

```
git clone git://github.com/spray/spray-template.git my-project
```

Then, from the project's root, I started sbt:

```
cd my-project
sbt
```

The problem is that the project never compiles and I always get the following errors:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/j3d/Projects/my-project/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/j3d/Projects/my-project/project/}my-project-build...
[info] Resolving io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.7.2 ...
[error] Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/io.spray/sbt-revolver/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/io.spray/sbt-revolver/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/spray/sbt-revolver_2.10_0.13/0.7.2/sbt-revolver-0.7.2.pom
[warn]  module not found: io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.7.2
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/io.spray/sbt-revolver/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/io.spray/sbt-revolver/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/j3d/.ivy2/local/io.spray/sbt-revolver/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/spray/sbt-revolver_2.10_0.13/0.7.2/sbt-revolver-0.7.2.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.7.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      io.spray:sbt-revolver:0.7.2 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      io.spray:sbt-revolver:0.7.2 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/home/j3d/Projects/my-project/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:my-project-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.7.2: not found
at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:165)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1365)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1399)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1397)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1402)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1396)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1419)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.7.2: not found
```

Comment: spray is deprecated. Please use akka-http.

Comment: Or http4s, if you like FP.

Comment: ah ok... didn't know. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

add following lines to build.sbt

```
 resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"
 Revolver.settings
```

and in plugin.sbt add

```
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.7.2")
```